# Axios get call returns undefined, even if I use async code

Tags: reactjs, axios

For this piece of code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.min.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-material.min.css';
import Grid from '../Common/Grid';
import axios from 'axios';

function GetJudete() {
  axios.get("http://localhost:5266/api/judete").then((response) =>
  {
    let data = response.data;
    return data;
  } 
  ).catch(err => {
    console.log("Eroare la aducerea datelor.");      
  })
};

function Localitati()
{
  let judete;
  useEffect(() => {
    judete = GetJudete();
  }, []);
  console.log(judete);
  
  const [columnDefs] = useState([
    { field: 'nume', filter: 'agTextColumnFilter', editable: true },
    { field: 'judetID', filter: 'agTextColumnFilter', editable: true },
  ])
  return (
    <Grid 
    baseLink='http://localhost:5266/api/localitati'
    columnDefs={columnDefs}
    />
  );
}

export default Localitati;
```

my `console.log()` prints undefined. I expected it to be filled with values, because I'm using async code in `GetJudete()` by using `Promises`.

I see that it does not work this way though.

Why and how can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: In order for react to update, you need to set a state after your ajax call is done https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two major reasons why you're seeing `undefined`:

1. Code in `useEffect` is run after render. That's why any update to `judete` would happen after you already logged it. (Once it's set correctly, you would need to trigger a rerender in order to see a second log line.)
2. Your `GetJudete` function doesn't return anything, that's why you still would be getting `undefined`. (Your promise does return something, but that's never used anywhere.)

Here's a way to work around both issues:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.min.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-material.min.css';
import Grid from '../Common/Grid';
import axios from 'axios';

async function GetJudete() {
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.get("http://localhost:5266/api/judete");
        return data;
    } catch (_) {
        console.log("Eroare la aducerea datelor.");      
    }
};

function Localitati()
{
  // Use a state instead of a local variable, so that React knows about updates
  const [judete, setJudete] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getJudeteAsync() {
      const result = await GetJudete();
      setJudete(result);
    }
    // Trigger the async function from your effect
    getJudeteAsync();
  }, []);

  // The first render will yield "undefined";
  // once the AJAX call is successfully done, the setJudete above will cause a re-render and you should see a second log line with an actual value
  console.log(judete);
  
  const [columnDefs] = useState([
    { field: 'nume', filter: 'agTextColumnFilter', editable: true },
    { field: 'judetID', filter: 'agTextColumnFilter', editable: true },
  ])
  return (
    <Grid 
    baseLink='http://localhost:5266/api/localitati'
    columnDefs={columnDefs}
    />
  );
}

export default Localitati;
```

Comment: Got it. Can I use GetJudete like this too? https://pastebin.com/YzMJef5D

Comment: Yes, you can. I prefer to be consistent about using async/await, though.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
async function getJudate(){
    await axios.get(...).then(...)
}
```

```js
useEffect(() => {
    let judate = getJudate()
    console.log(judate)
}, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to console.log data after it's resolved.

In your current code you are printing judetes when component is created. To fix your issue you should call console.log in `.then` since it's resolved some time after component creation.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems !

1. data fetching :

`GetJudete` function must return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
so try :

```js
async function GetJudete() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:5266/api/judete");
        let data = response.data;
        return data; 
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
};
```

2. [hooks data fetching](https://reactjs.org/link/hooks-data-fetching):

`useEffect` callbacks are synchronous to prevent race conditions so we need to put async function inside the `useEffect` callback
and also you should use states to do anything with your data other than that react don't know when something has changed to re-render component

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const data = await GetJudete();
    console.log(data);
    // setState is required here !
    return data;
  }
  fetchData();
}, [])
```